# How can I disable the non-exhaustive "when" expression inspection?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the following IntelliJ inspection:

`'when' expression on enum is recommended to be exhaustive`

because very often I use `when` expressions without listing all the possible values.

From what I can tell, there is no setting to disable this inspection in IntelliJ (though I've been wrong, before).

Is there some way to disable this inspection?

[image: img]

Comment: You can supress errors by `Alt+Enter` then selecting `>` symbol in the right side of the text and then supress errors or completely disable inspection for that warning which I won't recommend.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but there is no option to disable the inspection

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress it via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu, right arrow like any other inspection:

[image: Suppress]

See also the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections).

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to disable it. Not just suppress.

Comment: There is no way to disbale this specific inspection at the moment.

Comment: I guess some would raise their eyebrows at the idea of disabling this inspection. In a code I'm working on there are a lot of `if (x=A) {/*do stuff*/} else if (x=B) {/*do other stuff*/}`, and to me the `when` statement is just so much more readable than `if` and `else`s. But, only in about half of the cases do I really need to consider all options of `x`. If `x==C` I don't care about it, etc.

Comment: Any idea why I don't get the right arrows in IDEA 2020.3.3 (Ultimate Edition), and also manually adding the suppression does not work? See [this screenshot](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort/pull/3685#discussion_r599468799).